# Big Query Regex for Date ETL

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have data with Date info imported in Big Query in format 2/13/2016 , 3/4/2012 etc

I want to convert it into Date format like 02-12-2016 and 03-04-2012.
I want to use a Query to create a new column and use regex for the same.

I know the regex to match the first part (2) of 2/4/2012 will be something like

^(\d{1})(/|-)

Reg ex to match the the 2nd part with / would be

(/)(\d{1})(/)

I am wondering how to use these 2 regex along with REGEXP_EXTRACT and REGEXP_REPLACE to create a new column with these dates in correct format.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest just to convert to a `DATE` type column. For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', date_string) AS date
FROM (
  SELECT '2/13/2016' AS date_string UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/4/2012' AS date_string
);
```

Another option--if you want to keep the dates as strings--is to use `REPLACE`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  REPLACE(date_string, '/', '-') AS date
FROM (
  SELECT '2/13/2016' AS date_string UNION ALL
  SELECT '3/4/2012' AS date_string
);
```

Comment: SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', date_string) worked for us.. Thank a lot Elliot